# java.util.NoSuchElementException in main method using Scanner w/ input & output text files

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

Error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at PetOrganizer.main(PetOrganizer.java:23)
```

This is the main class which interacts with the the Pet Class which is also posted below. First time using FileWriter so if I'm doing something blantantly wrong here just let me know. Line 23 of my code for the main class is the like with "String name".

Edit: Added the input.txt file there is also an output.txt file that the program is meant to print to but it's empty

Code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class PetOrganizer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    //Intialize Text File along with Writer variables
    File TextFile = new File("input.txt");
    File OutputFile = new File("output.txt");
    FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(TextFile, true);
    FileWriter fOWriter = new FileWriter(OutputFile);
    PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(fOWriter);


    //Initialize Scanner Variable
    Scanner in = new Scanner(TextFile);


    //Gets input from user for pet #1
    System.out.println("Please enter what you would like your first pet to be named: ");
```

This is cut in the code is to show line 23 which is causing the error seen above

```
    String name =  in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter how old you would like "+name+" to be:");
    int age = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter what type of pet you would like(Dog, Cat, Mouse, Ferret): ");
    String pettype = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of "+name+"'s owner");
    String owner = in.nextLine();

    //Creates first instance of Pet and uses input from user
    Pet p1 = new Pet();
    p1.setPetAge(age);
    p1.setPetName(name);
    p1.setPetType(pettype);
    p1.setPetOwner(owner);

    //Gets input from user for pet #1
    System.out.println("Please enter what you would like your second pet to be named: ");
    name = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter how old you would like "+name+" to be:");
    age = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter what type of pet you would like(Dog, Cat, Mouse, Ferret): ");
    pettype = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of "+name+"'s owner");
    owner = in.nextLine();

    //Creates first instance of Pet and uses input from user
    Pet p2 = new Pet();
    p2.setPetAge(age);
    p2.setPetName(name);
    p2.setPetType(pettype);
    p2.setPetOwner(owner);      

    //Gets input from user for pet #1
    System.out.println("Please enter what you would like your third pet to be named: ");
    name = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter how old you would like "+name+" to be:");
    age = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter what type of pet you would like(Dog, Cat, Mouse, Ferret): ");
    pettype = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of "+name+"'s owner");
    owner = in.nextLine();

    //Creates first instance of Pet and uses input from user
    Pet p3 = new Pet();
    p3.setPetAge(age);
    p3.setPetName(name);
    p3.setPetType(pettype);
    p3.setPetOwner(owner);      

    //Outputs all of the instances of Pet with the info gathered from user input
    pWriter.println("/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
    pWriter.println("///////////////////PATIENT LIST//////////////////////////");
    pWriter.println("Pet 1");
    pWriter.println("Pet 1 Age: "+ p1.getPetAge());
    pWriter.println("Pet 1 Name: "+p1.getPetName());
    pWriter.println("Pet 1 Type: "+p1.getPetType());
    pWriter.println("Pet 1 Owner: "+p1.getPetOwner());
    pWriter.println("Pet 2");
    pWriter.println("Pet 2 Age: "+ p2.getPetAge());
    pWriter.println("Pet 2 Name: "+p2.getPetName());
    pWriter.println("Pet 2 Type: "+p2.getPetType());
    pWriter.println("Pet 2 Owner: "+p2.getPetOwner());
    pWriter.println("Pet 3");
    pWriter.println("Pet 3 Age: "+ p3.getPetAge());
    pWriter.println("Pet 3 Name: "+p3.getPetName());
    pWriter.println("Pet 3 Type: "+p3.getPetType());
    pWriter.println("Pet 3 Owner: "+p3.getPetOwner());
    pWriter.println("//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
    pWriter.println("//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");

    fWriter.close();
    pWriter.close();
    in.close();

}
```

}

Pet Class Code:

```
    public class Pet {
//Class Private Data Members
private String petName;
private int petAge;
private String petType; //Cat, Dog, Ferret, etc
private String petOwner;

//Constructor
public Pet()
{

}

//Public Methods
public String getPetName() {
    return petName;
}

public void setPetName(String name) {
    petName = name;
}

public int getPetAge() {
    return petAge;
}

public void setPetAge(int age) {
    petAge = age;
}

public String getPetType() {
    return petType;
}

public void setPetType(String type) {
    petType = type;
}

public String getPetOwner() {
    return petOwner;
}

public void setPetOwner(String owner) {
    petOwner = owner;
}
```

}

Input File:

```
    George
    18
    Dog
    Ben
    Fred
    19
    Ferret
    Carl
    Steve
    20
    Cat
    Dog
```

Comment: Do you want this `Scanner in = new Scanner(TextFile);` to be `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`?

Comment: "`at PetOrganizer.main(PetOrganizer.java:23)`" -- Which line is that? (Label it in your code.)

Comment: @brso05 I'm trying to use Scanner to read from a separate text file called input

Comment: @N.Sweeney then why are you prompting the user for input using `System.out`...?

Comment: Can you add the input file to your question?

Comment: @bradimus Added

Comment: @brso05 To be honest now that I take another look it seems unnecessary as there is a text file that I want the program to read this info from anyways, I'll remove this once the problem has been resolved

Comment: @N.Sweeney where is your text file stored?

Comment: @brso05 Within my main project folder but it's not with the classes or anything like that

Comment: @N.Sweeney try specifying the entire path to the file: `c:\etc...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use a file, using bufferedReader you can go through a text file, line by line until it is finished. For example if you had a text file that had

> Dog1
>
> Dog2

the first time it goes through the while loop, the string currentWord is "Dog1"
the second time it goes through the while loop, the string currentWord is "Dog2"
etc

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\words.txt")))
        {
            String currentWord;
            while ((currentWord = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
               //USE EACH OF YOUR STRINGS HERE i.e String dogName = currentWord
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

"C:\words.txt" refers to the location of the file you want to use.
to use this just import

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: Yeah I'm supposed to be taking information from a text file called input but just can't seem to get the line to work correctly

Comment: Edited, hope this helps

Comment: How would I go about using different variables in the while loop since I have a separate variable for each portion of my Pet instance and would it be possible to run a for loop that could read 4 lines so I could then run this loop 3 times for each Pet instance and it wouldn't just repeat the first 4 lines of the text file.